# Navigation between forms fires infiniteContainer refresh

Tags: codenameone

Two handcoded forms (A e B). Form A has a infinitecontainer (with multibuttons) that fetch data from a database. When i click in a multibutton in Form A it goes to Form B where it displays the corresponding record detail. I pass Form A as a variable to Form B to be able to navigate back to form A.

When i´m in Form B and call FormA.showBack() to go back to Form A it shows Form A but fires the infinitecontainer fetchComponents method - doing another database call - and i definitely do not want that...

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: show us some code! Sounds like the `InfiniteContainer` is behaving as expected, and you need to custom it for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have some code bound to the on show event callback either in code or in GUI but it's hard to tell. I suggest stepping over the code with a debugger.

Comment: Thanks Shai, but no code bound to the Show event callback. Simple form with a show. Will try again with the debugger.